# Why our website blog page is loading twice?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, symfony, debugging

Our website is written in Symfony Framework. There is a JavaScript code which i guess is making our website loading twice.

**URL**: https://www.drberg.com/blog/what-to-eat-for-your-body-type

Please visit the above website and you will get that how it is loading twice on every visit. I don't know what is wrong. Someone suggested that there may be some **backgournd-image** css selector which is forcing the website to load twice but i didn't found anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires = "";
      if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
      }
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
      var nameEQ = name + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
      }
      return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
      createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }

    var url = window.location.href;
    var fullpath = new URL(url).pathname;
    var splitpath = fullpath.split("/");
    var pathname = splitpath[2] + "/" + splitpath[3];
    var jsonObj = [];
    var cookie_name = "video_cookie";
    var x = readCookie(cookie_name);
    if (x) {
      var res = x.split(",");
      console.log(x);
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res.every(x = > x !== pathname))
        {
          res.push(pathname);
          var joinedArray = res.join(",");
          createCookie(cookie_name, joinedArray, 7);
          $.post(window.location.href, {
            update_views: "yes"
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      jsonObj.push(pathname);
      createCookie(cookie_name, jsonObj, 7);
      $.post(window.location.href, {
        update_views: "yes"
      });
      var x = readCookie(cookie_name);
      console.log(x);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your page isn't being reloaded. The content is being hidden, then revealed. Something is adding the class `.async-hide` to the html tag, and later in the page there is an inline css: `.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} `.

Comment: It's your Rocket Loader Javascript. Try moving this line to the very top of the <head>: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/9014afdb/cloudflare-static/rocket.min.js"></script> BTW: that page is a nightmare to look at, my adBlocker blocks 20% of the page and GTmetrix gives it a 10second page load time, way to long.